# Bandpass filter obtained by complementary transformation of lowpass Sallen & Key: what went wrong?

Tags: filter, ltspice, frequency-response, band-pass, sallen-key

I am considering the following lowpass Sallen & Key filter:

[image]

My components are the following

- \$R_1=10 k\Omega\$
- \$R_2=10 k\Omega\$
- \$C_1=150 nF\$
- \$C_2=1.65 nF\$

Now I have performed a complementary transformation to obtain a Bandpass filter. Here is the schematic on LTSpice

[image]

Now, when I simulate this circuit I get a very odd response:
[image]

It doesn't look at all like a bandpass filter. It looks like a low pass one, but I know that is because of the OPAMP own frequency response.
What went wrong with my simulation, why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

Solved: When applying the complementary transformation I forgot to swap my infinity resistance r1 and my zero resistance r2. The positive terminal of the OPAMP should be connected to ground.

Comment: Correct - now you have a bandpass circuit using the multi-feedback topology. The opamp is assumed to have an infinite gain.

Answer (score 1):

You have positive feedback in your circuit. The output is latched high. The reason for the fall off at higher frequencies is the internal behaviour of the op-amp as you've mentioned.